# An error occurred submitting the question/answer/edit

Tags: support, error-message, ssl

Stack Exchange usually works flawlessly but lately I've been unable make posts – questions, answers and edits. When pressing the Submit button, Stack Exchange displays a red pop-up box saying *"An error occurred submitting the ..."*.

After looking around a bit, I noticed that SSL was disabled on some networks on Stack Exchange, in Google Chrome displaying the "exclamation mark in circle"-symbol, representing non-private connections.

I therefore thought the problem was SSL-related. Strangely, on some network sites I get a SSL connection *sometimes*, but not at other times.

***But even now***, I'm on Meta SE with a supposedly active SSL connection (green keylock icon), and I can't submit this very question due to *"An error occurred while submitting the question"*.

I'm using the [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-Everywhere) extension for Chrome, so tried disabling it and Chrome antivirus plug-ins, but I'm still getting the same problem. I'm therefore not sure what the cause could be.

Are any other users having the same problem at the moment (2016-09-15–2016-09-16) or should I have other causes for concerns? I'm on a home network and there's no network administrator except me.

---

*N.B.:* [There *are* quite a few posts on this error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=error%20occurred), but is there any consensus? There seems to be many possible problems. Will be happy to mark this question as duplicate when directed to an answer that resolves the issue.